# How to filter data using spark.read in place?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I try read data in Delta format from ADLS. I want read some portion of that data using filter in place. Same approach worked for me during reading JDBC format

```
query = f"""
    select * from {table_name} 
    where 
       createdate < to_date('{createdate}','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') or
       modifieddate < to_date('{modifieddate}','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
    """

return spark.read \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", url) \
    .option("query", query) \
    .option("user", username) \
    .option("password", password) \
    .option("driver", "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver") \
    .load()
```

So I tried to create in similar way reading delta using query but it reads whole table.

```
return spark.read \
    .format("delta") \
    .option("query", query) \
    .load(path)
```

How could I solve this issue without reading full df and then filter it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spark uses a functionality called [predicate pushdown](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/content/spark-sql-Optimizer-PushDownPredicate.html) to optimize queries.
In the first case, the filters can be passed on to the oracle database.

Delta does not work that way. There can be optimisations through data skipping and Z-ordering, but since you are essentially querying parquet files, you have to read the all of them in memory and filter afterwards.

Comment: ...can you help me on how to apply filter while reading data from mongodb. My query reading 55M collections then filtering the data to process